# Error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, .net, io

I am getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

From the following line of code:

```
Directory.Move(location, newLocation);
```

Where location and newLocation are strings that are defined.

A little before that, I use the following I/O methods:

```
String[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(location);
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
Directory.Exists(location);
```

Where the location String is the same as the location String in the line that is currently giving me an error.

I then go on to use the directories and files in the arrays, but never open a file.

Is there something like a close I need to apply to getDirectories and getFiles or does my problem lie somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem myself. I tried moving the directory to a subdirectory of itself which, of course, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using any stream or `IDisposable` directly, so there's nothing to close or dispose of.

As the error suggests: are you sure no other process is using those files/directories?

Also, you say you're using the directories and files in the arrays. How exactly are you using them?

Comment: Does a file explorer window (the one that comes with windows) count?

Comment: I loop through them to get data from the names (extention, name)

Comment: Just regular string manipulation then? That's fine then. You can use this tool to check which process is using the file: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Crazy idea, highly unlikely - try calling `GC.Collect();` right before you try to move the directory. Let me know if it works.

Comment: GC.Collect(); didnt do anything.
Also, I can't become any wiser from process explorer. How would I see which directory is being used by which process?

Comment: I just edited my post because I saw that I was Directory.exists()

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution which refers to another which runs in the background.  The easiest option was to clean/rebuild/build and re-run both projects.  Tried other less intrusive advice which didnt work!